# How to get data (list) into <s:select> tag from database via Action class in struts2 framework

Tags: xml, list, select, struts2, action

I have got a problem with  tag in struts2.I really don't know about perform of this tag

Before,I have a list of country in my database what I want get it into `<s:select>`.I tried with 
jsp page(where there is my  tag):

```
<s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Search Engines" list="country" name="yoursearch"></s:select>
```

Action class:

```
 public class ShowSelect extends ActionSupport{
    private List<String> country;



    public ShowSelect() {

        country = new ArrayList<String>();
        country.add("google.com");
        country.add("bing.com");
        country.add("yahoo.com");
        country.add("baidu.com");

    }
    public String display() {
        return "success";
    }

    public List<String> getSearchEngine() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setSearchEngine(List<String> country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

File struts.xml

```
<action name="search" class="controller.ShowSelect">
   <result name="success">Select.jsp</result>
</action>
```

.But,on browser occur error as follows:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list': The requested list key '' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:522)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:416)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:389)
root cause

tag 'select', field 'list': The requested list key '' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
    org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:358)
    org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
    org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:105)
    org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:856)
    org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:510)
    org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    org.apache.jsp.Product.ShowListProduct_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fselect_005f0(ShowListProduct_jsp.java:253)
    org.apache.jsp.Product.ShowListProduct_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fdiv_005f0(ShowListProduct_jsp.java:115)
    org.apache.jsp.Product.ShowListProduct_jsp._jspService(ShowListProduct_jsp.java:70)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:389)
```

What I need : getting list into  from database via Action class

Could you help me? Please

Comment: what kind of database do you want to list get from?

Comment: Populate your list in action method or use `prepare`.

Answer (score 1):

It is showing problem because you don't have getter & setter for your list in action class.
Write `getCountry()` & `setCountry()` method inside your action. It will surely work fine.

Comment: I did.but everything isn't still fine

Comment: You don't have 'execute()'method in your action. You have written your code in constructor. I have never tried it with constructor & It is also not working in your code. So write 'execute( )' method & put your code inside it.

Comment: Sorry you                                                               This is really code

Comment: What does this mean "Sorry you This is really code" ? Show your updated code for further help.

Comment: Sorry....I mistook.This is my new ask about <s:select>.Please help me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548279/how-to-get-data-to-put-into-select-tag-in-struts-2

Comment: So,Do you think cause by web.xml?                                     Because.Once,I run project that on browser occur error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException..After that,I add  into file web.xml  as follows: <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class> 
     
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>                                                 => well done.But in case,I can't how to resolve

Comment: As far as my knowledge, Exception you have posted is not at all concerned with the any configuration in web.xml or struts.xml. This exception comes when you are trying to access or display a list on jsp but you haven't passed it from your action class OR you don't have getter & setter of respective list.

Comment: Actually.I  don't think there is any line of bad code in my project ,I  tried a tutorial from http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/ . I have done as the whole of code in this tutorial.But I can't receive good result.Can I give your account Facebook or YM? Can you use Teamview software to help me?